# Proper etiquette when editing a post to fix code formatting?

Tags: discussion, editing

The code posted [in this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286422/why-would-we-need-to-rollback-twice-before-closing-in-a-finally-block) looks (to me, at least) very poorly formatted, with the opening and closing curly braces on different indentation levels.

Would it be appropriate to edit the code block to align the try-catch blocks to make the code more readable?

Comment: As the one that finally went in and cleaned it up, yes. One of the core problems to the formatting was a mixture of tabs and spaces. An earlier version of the text was easier to format than the attempted reformatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

However, and it's a big however, you need to make sure that you don't alter the code in any other way. It's probably not *quite* as important here as it is on Stack Overflow, but editing code carries the risk that you might edit away the very problem that the OP is asking about.

Also, the poor formatting won't be the only thing that's wrong with the question so address and other issues like spelling, grammar and formatting of the explanatory text too.

And be prepared for your edit to be rejected if the reviewers think you've changed the code too much.